How can I solve permission issue with accessing an url content without messing with Sandbox?
I want read the content of a url but this code make an issue about permission in macOS, I tested this code in iOS, it works, but in macOS make the permission issue, I know removing the sandbox would solve the issue, but I cannot use this way because I need to lunch this app in appstore, so how to solve this problem?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isShowing: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Button("Import Folder") {
                isShowing.toggle()
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $isShowing, allowedContentTypes: [.folder], allowsMultipleSelection: false, onCompletion: { results in
            
            switch results {
            case .success(let items):
                
                print("count: " + String(items.count))
                
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                
                for item in items {
                    
                    print(item.path)
                    
                    lookToURL(item: item)
                    
                }
                
                print("- - - - - - - - - - -")
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
            
        })
    }
}




func lookToURL(item: URL) {
    
    isItemDirectory(at: item, result: { itemResult in
        
        if let itemIsDirectory: Bool = itemResult {
            
            if (itemIsDirectory) {
                
                print("Item is a folder!", "Name:", item.lastPathComponent)
                
                contentsOfDirectory(url: item, contents: { contents in
                    
                    for content in contents {
                        lookToURL(item: content)
                    }
                    
                })
                
            }
            else {
                print("Item is a file!", "Name:", item.lastPathComponent)
            }
            
        }
        else {
            print("Item is not a folder or file!")
        }
        
    })
    
}





func contentsOfDirectory(url: URL, contents: ([URL]) -> Void) {
    
    if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path)) {
        
        if let unwrappedValueOfIsDirectory: Bool = isItemDirectory(at: url) {
            
            if (unwrappedValueOfIsDirectory) {
                
                do {
                    
                    let contentsOfDirectory = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
                    contents(contentsOfDirectory)
                    
                }
                catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                
            }
            else {
                print("URL is a file!")
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    else {
        print("URL is not a folder or file!")
    }
    
}


func isItemDirectory(at url: URL, result: (Bool?) -> Void) {
    
    do {
        result(try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey]).isDirectory)
    }
    catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        result(nil)
    }
    
}

func isItemDirectory(at url: URL) -> Bool? {
    
    do {
        return (try url.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey]).isDirectory)
    }
    catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
    
}

The error:

count: 1





/Volumes/mac Drive/My Releases


Item is a folder! Name: My Releases


The file “My Releases” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.





https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app-sandbox#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16

what if a user wants give access to a folder that contains lots of mp3 and more folders inside that those have also mp3`s, the user want access all folders inside the folder for playing the mp3, what we can do about it?

The user could provide full disk access, or you can do the stuff explained in the documentation about entitlements and security scoped bookmarks.

@matt: I saved the url as bookMark and then I read the bookmark, using the bookmark url would solve the issue, but why I do not need bookmark work in iOS? also I like to learn about provide full disk access, do you know a link about it?

Try to use url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource before accessing contents inside the user-selected folder.
By the way, you'll need url.bookmarkData if you want to maintain permission even if user has rename the folder or restarts your app.
